# R Shiny error when using renderUI: object not found

Tags: r, shiny

For some reason, Shiny doesn't think my `renderUI` exists. The code is painfully simple. We have a dataframe of customers:
`DF_custs <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,3), val=c(10, 20, 100, 200))`.

You just select an ID and get a value back:

[image]

But I want to implement a way to send the values back to the user on a dropdown. So I proceeded with a `renderUI`.

The problem is with
`output$dupes<-renderUI({selectInput('dupes', 'These are dupes:', choices=get_cust()$val, selected=get_cust()$val[1,])})`

This line is here to allow you to see, for example, that the ID `3` has two values for `val`. These two values will populate a dropdown list. Later on I hope to build off of this, but for now this is all I'm trying to do. Very simple.

I keep getting the error `Error in output$dupes <- renderUI({ : object 'output' not found`.

Everything looks fine to me. I have a `renderUI` and it's associated `uiOutput`. I don't see any syntax problems and there are no missing arguments. What could possibly be going wrong?

### app.R

```
DF_custs <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,3), val=c(10, 20, 100, 200))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  get_cust <- reactive({
    cust <- DF_custs[which(DF_custs$ID == input$num), ]
    return(cust$val)})

  output$result <- renderText({ 
    ans <- get_cust()
    paste("Your value: ", ans)})
    }

  output$dupes<-renderUI({
    selectInput('dupes', 'These are dupes:', choices=get_cust()$val, selected=get_cust()$val[1,])})


ui <- fluidPage(
      numericInput(inputId="num", label="Pick an ID: ", value=1),
      uiOutput("dupes"),

      mainPanel(textOutput("result"))

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: can't reproduce, my render text shows `Your value: 100 Your value: 200` when 3 is selected. When are you getting the error? When you try and run  the shinyApp line or when you put in a specific value

Comment: In your code `output$dupes` isn't in the `server` function

Comment: @MrFlick: `R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)`, `shiny_0.12.1`

Comment: And in `get_cust <- reactive` you already return `val` col so `get_cust()$val` won't work

Comment: I think you just have a misplaced `}`. The one just before `output$dupes<-renderUI` seems out of place. It's closing the `server` function so the local `output` variable is no longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this `server function` :

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  get_cust <- reactive({
    #cust <- DF_custs[which(DF_custs$ID == input$num), ]
    #return(cust$val)
    DF_custs
    })

  output$result <- renderText({ 
    ans <- get_cust()[which(DF_custs$ID == input$num), "val"]
    paste("Your value: ", ans)})

  output$dupes<-renderUI({
    selectInput('dupes', 'These are dupes:', choices=get_cust()$val,     selected=get_cust()$val[1])
  })
}
```

Comment: ugggg....Victorp thank you. Ughhh. Forehead slapping.

Comment: I'm going to delete this question since it really won't serve anyone in the future. It was basically a missing brace.

Comment: @MattO'Brien this question just saved me. Current forehead slap count: 2.