# In R Shiny, use the value from an SelectInput that was populated by a previous choice

Tags: r, shiny

I have a very simple Shiny app.

I want to select an ID and a Date, and get the result.

The data is simple
`DF_custs <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,3), Date=c('1/1/2010', '1/1/2011', '1/1/2012', '1/1/2013'), result=c(100, 200, 300, 400))`

And the UI is set up and currently looks like this:

[image]

Say, I choose ID number 3. Then, the Select date menu is populated. Next I select a date. So far so good.

My question is, what kind of object to I need to implement, in order to display the correct result which depends on the date I've just selected? As it stands this functionality is missing and the app just burps out both results, no matter what.

In looking to solve this, I'm not sure if `SelectInput` will be of much use. I see that the `SelectInput` that is used alongside the `renderUI` does what it is supposed to do, which is to render the dropdown in the UI. How would I send the value in the `SelectInput` *back* over to the server?

I could try some sort of modification of `output$result`, such as

```
  output$result <- renderText({ 
    ans <- get_cust()$result
    ans <- ans[which(ans$Date==output$dates), Date]
    paste("Result: ", ans)})
```

but now I'm in some Dr Who paradox where the `ans` can't exist if the `ans` didn't already exist.

For me, working with reactivity in Shiny gets uncomfortable when there are sequences of actions that need to be performed, before a final result. This inevitably means that things need to be evaluated at different times. Shiny is easy when things fire all at once and all the reactive stuff happily executes together. But even in simple toy situations like this, I realize I need another tool in my toolbox. Any help is greatly appreciated.

## app.R

```
DF_custs <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,3), Date=c('1/1/2010', '1/1/2011', '1/1/2012', '1/1/2013'), result=c(100, 200, 300, 400))
DF_custs$Date <- as.character(DF_custs$Date)

## app.R ##
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  get_cust <- reactive({
    cust <- DF_custs[which(DF_custs$ID == input$ID), ]
    return(cust)})
  
  output$result <- renderText({ 
    ans <- get_cust()$result
    paste("Result: ", ans)})
    

  output$dates<-renderUI({
    selectInput('dates', 'Select date:', choices=get_cust()$Date, selected=get_cust()$Date)})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
      numericInput(inputId="ID", label="Pick an ID: ", value=1),
      uiOutput("dates"),
      
      mainPanel(textOutput("result"))
      
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

PS thanks to @Victorpfor his help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326697/r-shiny-error-when-using-renderui-object-not-found).

Comment: It's unclear to me why you don't just use `input$dates`. Is it somehow insufficient?

Comment: I have `output$dates` to present to the user the date options. You are saying I collect the value back with `input$dates`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. When you run `selectInput('dates', ...)`, Shiny automatically creates a `dates` element in `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me again, just do :

```
output$result <- renderText({ 
   ans <- get_cust()$result
   ans <- ans[DF_custs$Date[which(DF_custs$ID == input$ID)] == input$dates]
   paste("Result: ", ans)
})
```

You can probably do something more efficient but it will work, if you want to check that `input$dates` is defined you can add a `if` with `!is.null(input$dates)` for preventing the code to execute.

Comment: This works but I don't understand how. `input$dates` doesn't exit until after `output$result` finishes executing, but `output$result` requires `input$dates` as a condition!

Comment: You can type `showReactLog()` for see the reactive log visualizer, maybe it will help you to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using `observeEvent` and `reactive` in the server and `selectInput` for the date in the ui:

```
DF_custs <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,3),
           Date=c('1/1/2010', '1/1/2011',
                  '1/1/2012', '1/1/2013'),         
           result=c(100, 200, 300, 400))
DF_custs$Date <- as.character(DF_custs$Date)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  result <- reactive({paste("Result: ", input$ID, " @ ", input$Date) })
  output$result <- renderText({ result()})
  observeEvent(input$ID, {updateSelectInput(session, "Date", 
               choices=DF_custs[input$ID == DF_custs$ID, "Date"])}) 

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId="ID", label="Pick an ID: ", value=1,
               min=1, max=3, step=1),
  selectInput(inputId="Date",label="Pick a date",
               choices=c("Choose") , selectize = FALSE ),
  mainPanel(textOutput("result"))

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope this helps! There are more examples @ [RStudio](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html)